# Which construction is correct?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

I'm not sure if my sentence is correct. I have doubts if the first sentence correct in its constellation. Is it

```
In cities the location of a mobile phone on 100 to 500 m can be accurately determined.
```

or is it?

```
In cities the location of a mobile phone can be accurately determined on 100 to 500 m.
```

In the case that no sentence is correct I want to say the the position of a smartphone can be accurately determined within 100 to 500 m. In cities the mobile phone network is more accuarate than outside.

Comment: In English, "constellation" means "a named set of stars that form a picture in the sky". Perhaps you meant "construction"?

Comment: @Martha I correct it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"In cities the location of a mobile phone can be accurately determined to within 100 to 500 m."

You wouldn't say "on 100 to 500 m" because the location is not "on" the distance. The location is "within" the distance.